# Filter or seperate SQL query based on column value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, express

I have a query to get a list of exercises from circuit:

```
SELECT * 
FROM workouts
INNER JOIN circuits ON workouts.id = circuits.workout_id
INNER JOIN circuit_steps ON circuits.id = circuit_steps.circuit_id
INNER JOIN exercises ON exercises.id = circuit_steps.exercise_id
WHERE workouts.id = ${req.params.id}
```

The current result is this (basic fields for brevity)

```
[
  {
    name: "Push Up",
    circuit_id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Bicep Curl",
    circuit_id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Squat",
    circuit_id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Walk out",
    circuit_id: 2
  }
]
```

I want to be able to `GROUP` the results by the `circuit_steps.circuit_id` so the result is like this:

```
[
  [
    { name: 'Push Up', circuit_id: 1},
    { name: 'Bicep Curl', circuit_id: 1},
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Squat', circuit_id: 2},
    { name: 'Walk Out', circuit_id: 2},
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT cs.circuit_id, string_agg(e.name, ',') as execise_names
FROM workouts w INNER JOIN
     circuits c
     ON w.id = c.workout_id INNER JOIN
     circuit_steps cs
     ON c.id = cs.circuit_id INNER JOIN
     exercises e
     ON e.id = cs.exercise_id
WHERE workouts.id=${req.params.id}
GROUP BY cs.circuit_id
```

Comment: This will group the exercises names into 1 object `execise_names: "Push Up,Rest,Walk Out,Rest,Bridge,Rest"` where as I want two arrays of objects